# Recoger valor de input modal con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

estoy modificando un codigo que envia los tickets de venta por whatsApp.
En teoria se abre una ventana modal y se ingresa el numero de telefono al hacer click en enviar este deberia enviar al numero ingresado el mensaje de whatsapp, pero no logro recoger la informacion del modal para ponerla en una variabl

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
    aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Título del modal</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="box-body">
                    <!-- ENTRADA PARA NUMERO -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-cash-register"></i></span> 
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="NUMERO TELEFONICO" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="enviarMensaje()" >ENVIAR</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function enviarMensaje() {
        var tel= document.getElementById("telefono").value;

        var url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=52$(tel)";

        window.open(url);
        }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea tu url de esta manera

```
var url = `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=52${tel}`;
```

Estás intentando usar *cadenas de plantilla*, pero la sintaxis es con llaves {} y no con paréntesis () y además el string ha de ir encerrado en comillas a derechas o graves.

Alternativamente también lo puedes hacer de una forma más *tradicional*

```
var url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=52" + tel;
```

Comment: gracias por tu aportacion

Answer (score 0):

lo resolvi de esta manera gracias por sus aportaciones

```js
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let telefono = document.querySelector("#telefono").value;

        let url = `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+52${telefono}
        window.open(url);
       

    });
    </script>
```